# Formatting h2 with css

Tags: css

I would like to insert a little extra space before each `<h2>` tag I use. Is there a way to accomplish this with CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
h2 { margin-top: 5px ) //replace 5 with whatever you want
```

Comment: Oh yes, I tried that, but I just remembered I had put another `margin` at the bottom of the h2, overriding that... clumsy me :)

Answer (score 2):

Padding works too:

```
h2 { padding-top: 5px; }
```